# How do you correctly escape characters in string for example %

Tags: formatting, escape

I am trying to escape some text for a shell command, but i am gettig stuck with this error.

Not enough arguments for format string

From what i can tell its trying to interpret the % symbols.

This snippet produce the error when i output the command, but its fine if i pass it to shell-command.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq dc-str-addresses "{{printf \\\"%.30s\\\" .Name}}{{printf\\\"%.22s\\\" .IPAddress }}")
(message (format "test %s" dc-str-addresses))
#+END_SRC
```

Where as this one outputs fine, but give me %% when i pass it to shell-command so how can i make this work for both ? can i tell lisp to ignore the % symbols in my string ?

```
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp
(setq dc-str-addresses "{{printf \\\"%%.30s\\\" .Name}}{{printf \\\"%%.22s\\\" .IPAddress }}")
(message (format "test %s" dc-str-addresses))
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: test {{printf \"%.30s\" .Name}}{{printf \"%.22s\" .IPAddress }}
```

I am running the command through shell in this manner.
    (shell-command dc-str-addresses)

Comment: Can you show you are passing this to shell-command (every combination I've tried just gives me a syntax error)? Thanks!

Comment: (shell-command dc-str-addresses) Thats all i am doing when you say it produces a syntax error do you mean shell is ? because the above is not valid shell command but it should error and show you the command it was trying to run thats how i can see when there is %% in the result.

Comment: I can't actually figure out what your question is, but you should probably take a look at `C-h f message` because you're not using it correctly.

Comment: Thanks, your exactly right if you want to make that an answer I will happily accept it. (message "%s" dc-str-addresses) is exactly what i needed

Comment: Your question title and your accepted answer, and thus your actual question, are asking different things. (-1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of:

```
(message (format "test %s" dc-str-addresses))
```

You want:

```
(message "test %s" dc-str-addresses)
```

`message` accepts the same arguments as `format`:

> (message FORMAT-STRING &rest ARGS)
>
> The first argument is a format control string, and the rest are data
>   to be formatted under control of the string.  See `format' for details.
>
> **Note: Use (message "%s" VALUE) to print the value of expressions and
>   variables to avoid accidentally interpreting `%' as format specifiers.**